# Embarcadero C++ Builder - Public Function

Tags: c++, function, c++builder, public

I got two forms (form_1 and form_2).
I made a function inside body of form_1.

```
void ExampleFunction() {
    ShowMessage("I'm example function inside form_1");
}
```

and I want to call it from form_2.

I tryed to add this function to header file of form_1.

```
public: // User declarations
    __fastcall Tform_2(TComponent* Owner);
    void ExampleFunction();
};
```

but when I want to call it from form_2, like :

```
form_2->ExampleFunction();
```

Builder gives me a error : "[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external"

So how can I do it properly to make it work ?

Comment: There's a lot of cases go to through in that "dupe"... might be pretty scary for a beginner

Answer (score 2):

You are contradicting yourself.  You said you want to implement the function in Form_1 and call it from Form_2, but you are trying to implement it in Form_2 and call it from outside of Form_2.

In any case, you declared the function as a member of the Tform_2 class, so you need to qualify the function's body as such:

```
void Tform_2::ExampleFunction() {
    ShowMessage("I'm example function inside form_1");
}
```